# Remove header fields generated by http input plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

When I use [http](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html) input plugin, Logstash adds the following fields to Elasticsearch:

- headers.http_accept
- headers.content_type
- headers.request_path
- headers.http_version
- headers.request_method
- ...

How can I remove all these fields starting with `headers.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these are all pathed, that means they all are hierarchical under `[headers]` as far as the logstash configs go. This will probably do wonders for you:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "headers" ]
  }
}
```

Which should drop the `[headers][http_accept]`, `[headers][content_type]` and so on fields.